# Dealing with cache and updated JSON files in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, caching

I'm building an app where I add and delete items from a JSON file. 
I've encountered the following problem: When I delete an item, it gets reflected in the frontend (the item disappears), but **it takes a couple of hard page reloads** for the app to read the new JSON file produced by my PHP file instead of the cached one.

If I just reload once, it will just read the JSON file in cache, which doesn't reflect the changes made.

Is there any way to deal with this issue directly in AngularJS?

Here's my Angular code:

```
 $scope.remove = function(array, index){
    if($scope.totsselected){
      array.splice(index, 1);
      $http.post("deleteall.php", {
          data : array
      })
      .then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $http.get('data/all.json')
          .then(function (response) {
              $scope.productesgenerals = response.data;
              console.log($scope.productesgenerals);
          }).catch(function (error) {
        });
      }); 
    }
)};
```

And my PHP code:

```
<?php

$contentType = explode(';', $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']); 

$rawBody = file_get_contents("php://input"); // Read body
$data = json_decode($rawBody); // Then decode it
$all = $data->data; 

$jsonData = json_encode($all);
file_put_contents('data/all.json', $jsonData); 
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have $http caching turned on.  Try disabling it for this request

```
$http.get('data/all.json', {cache: false})
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching

If that doesn't work (it is still cached), then it sounds like server-side caching.  You can bust this by sending a unique query string.

```
$http.get('data/all.json?_=' + Date.now(), {cache: false})
```

This will make each request a unique request and should prevent the server side caching.

One caveat is that since you are ignoring the caching, you lose all the performance benefits of caching.